# Dreamweaver (Mac) crash on connect SFTP

Tags: macos, crash, dreamweaver

For some reason my dreamweaver starts crashing on connecting a remote server which I was always able to connect to before..

Any other site from my configured sites are still working. Also sites which are on the same server with the exact same type of connection (through VPN tunnel, sftp etc).

I've already tried to clear dreamweaver cache, use another local folder, use another remote folder, configure the site connection configuration again, disabling cache in config, but nothing seems to make it work again.

I don't know which part of the log is most important, but I guess this part:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/MacOS/Dreamweaver
__TEXT                 0000000000001000-000000000197e000 [ 25.5M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/MacOS/Dreamweaver
```

If you need any other part of the log let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the question is still open but I was able to solve the issue. Seems it had to do something with the server I was connecting to. Cronjobs where stacking up on each other causing all processes being in use. The server couldn't make another process for the ftp connection and Dreamweaver didn't handle that well. Killing the cronjobs (or restarting the server) can fix the issue and everything works fine.